# Rewriting paths for wordpress when it is not in a domain's root folder

Tags: wordpress

Inside the root folder of `domain.com` I have a number of folders, which includes a folder that keeps the wordpress files and is called `wp`.

In order to make the URLs look appropriately, I have include the `.htaccess` and `index.php` files in the root.

here is the .htaccess file content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and here is the index.php:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Now whenever I go to domain.com it goes all well. But as soon as I follow at least one link inside the page, the URLs change to domain.com/wp/link and the dashboard is only accessed through `domain.com/wp/wp-admin`.

What I want to do is to get rid of the `wp/` in the URLs.

Comment: You can check in Wordpress dashboard Settings -> General and make sure the Site URL is domain.com and the home url is domain.com/wp/. Then just update your permalinks by going to Settings -> Permalinks and saving the permalink structure.

Comment: Thanks, that was all I needed. Could you please submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: Added as answer @Domas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in Wordpress dashboard Settings -> General and make sure the Site URL is domain.com and the home url is domain.com/wp/. Then just update your permalinks by going to Settings -> Permalinks and saving the permalink structure.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your wordpress url is like your site url

go to setting->

general setting -> check site url it must be www.sitename.com or your wordpress url must be same as your site url